# Copy DIV HTML from another URL

Tags: python, php, jquery, wordpress, cpanel

Hello I would like to copy Div HTML from another URL and paste/echo it on my website using Python or Jquery
Can someone help please

Im using Cpanel and Wordpress

Answer (score 1):

this should point you in the right direction:

```
var response =  $.get('url');
var content = $(response).find('div_id').html(); // get the html of the div
```

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var response =  $.get('https://www.trade-ideas.com/ticky/ticky.html?symbol=amzn');
var content = $(response).find('span12').html(); // get the html of the div


    </script> 

Doesnt work, or Im doing something wrong

Comment: change to $(response).find('#span12').html();

Comment: if its a class then it should be $(response).find('.span12').html();

Comment: Ok i did it but still not working, im not very familiar with javascript.
Should I echo the VAR after that ? if so how 

thank you very much

Comment: Can u post a screenshot of the error you are getting in your console?

Comment: Im not getting any error just blank page

Comment: https://tradingjunkie.space/test.html

Comment: consol.log(content); //add to your code, and refresh, it should log the content of the div to the console..

or $('body').append(content); // to add it to the page

Comment: just tried none of them work :(

Comment: The request is being blocked by the server

Comment: humm ok , will it work with python ?

Comment: not unless trade-ideas.com whitelists tradingjunkie.com